# bibliography with all authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I wish to make a bibliography where each publication lists all the author names, without the use of "et al.".

I have searched stack exchange and tried many different approaches. Most posts recommend `biblatex` and setting `maxnames` and `minnames` but I have found that this doesn't work. The following code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}

\usepackage{txfonts} %Schriftart Times New Roman

\usepackage[
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  maxnames=1000,
  minnames=100,
  backend=biber
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Gives output that compiles to this:

> Banos, Daniel Trejo, Daniel L McCartney, Tom Battram, Gibran Hemani, Rosie M Walker,Stewart W Morris, Qian Zhang, David J Porteous, Allan F McRae, Naomi R Wray, et al. “Bayesian reassessment of the epigenetic architecture of complex traits”. In:bioRxiv(2018), p. 450288.

So still has an "et al." I suppose I have to modify a style file somehow but I cannot work this out either and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the entry in question.

Comment: Please show us the `.bib` entry you are using. If you indeed set `maxnames=1000,` and the output still shows "et al." despite not printing 1000 names, chances are the entry has an explicit `and others` in the `author` list. In that case you need to edit the `.bib` entry to give all names.

Comment: @moewe you are correct, I had made this most simple and most stupid mistake and I hadn't realised. Thanks you to all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bibtex` and `\bibliographystyle{plain}` you can list all the author names in the references. Here is your code which is modified

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}

\usepackage{txfonts} %Schriftart Times New Roman

% \usepackage[
%   bibstyle=authortitle,
%   citestyle=authoryear,
%   maxnames=1000,
%   minnames=100,
%   backend=biber
%   ]{biblatex}

% \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

%---------added---------------
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{bayesian}

% \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Below is the contents of bibliography file `bayesian.bib`

```
@article {Banos450288,
    author = {Banos, Daniel Trejo and McCartney, Daniel L. and Battram, Tom and Hemani, Gibran and Walker, Rosie M. and Morris, Stewart W. and Zhang, Qian and Porteous, David J. and McRae, Allan F. and Wray, Naomi R. and Visscher, Peter M. and Haley, Chris S. and Evans, Kathryn L. and Deary, Ian J. and McIntosh, Andrew M. and Marioni, Riccardo E. and Robinson, Matthew R.},
    title = {Bayesian reassessment of the epigenetic architecture of complex traits},
    elocation-id = {450288},
    year = {2018},
    doi = {10.1101/450288},
    publisher = {Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory},
    URL = {https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/10/22/450288},
    eprint = {https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/10/22/450288.full.pdf},
    journal = {bioRxiv}
}
```

Compile the file using `LaTeX + BibTex (x2) + LaTeX`. Output of the code is shown below[image: all author names listed]

Comment: The OP asked about the modern biblatex system.

Comment: If one uses the entry you posted with the `biblatex` code from the OP there is no "et al." either. So this is no good reason to go back to BibTeX and `plain.bst` from `biblatex` (there are certainly other, valid reasons, but this is not one). I strongly suspect something fish is going on with the OP's `.bib` entry (or there is some other `biblatex` code in their document that they are not showing us).

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I cannot replicate the issue you say you're experiencing if I employ the bib entry provided by the publisher (https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/450288v1):

[image]

The bib entry that may be obtained from the link given above actually isn't quite  right: It uses the entry type `@article` even though cited piece is more a preprint than a journal article. (It got published in *Nature Communications* earlier this year.) I therefore changed the entry type from `@article` to `@misc`, deleted the `journal` field, and changed the name of the `publisher` field to `organization`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{refs.bib}
@misc{Banos450288,
    author = {Banos, Daniel Trejo and McCartney, Daniel L. and Battram, Tom and Hemani, Gibran and Walker, Rosie M. and Morris, Stewart W. and Zhang, Qian and Porteous, David J. and McRae, Allan F. and Wray, Naomi R. and Visscher, Peter M. and Haley, Chris S. and Evans, Kathryn L. and Deary, Ian J. and McIntosh, Andrew M. and Marioni, Riccardo E. and Robinson, Matthew R.},
    title = {Bayesian reassessment of the epigenetic architecture of complex traits},
    elocation-id = {450288},
    year = {2018},
    organization = {Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory},
    URL = {https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/10/22/450288},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,vmargin=25mm,hmargin=30mm}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 'txfonts' is obsolete

\usepackage[
          bibstyle=authortitle,
          citestyle=authoryear,
          maxnames=1000,
          backend=biber
          ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{Banos450288}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```